# Table being cut off after first page

Tags: telerik-reporting

I'm working on creating a report for a client. I've attached an image to show what I'm expecting (the left side), and what I'm getting after the first page (the right side). The Group Detail section is comprised of a table. I've tried adjusting the Keep Together properties of the table, the group, the section. Just about everywhere I could think of. It prints just fine on page one, and then on page 2, starts getting funky and cut off. I've even set a pagebreak at the end of the Detail Section. Any ideas or suggestions? I've also posted this over on the Telerik forums. However, after I did so, I was told by friends/co-workers that answers there can often be slow in the coming.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When we use Table in Telerik Reporting, we should embed Table in Panel in design time.
so that it can properly fit on page when it gets previewed in ReportViewer and we will restrict a table to being cut or go to second page.